# How to gitignore .idea/libraries and still keep a history of dependency versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have not added `.idea/libraries/` to my .gitignore because I noticed that the changes inside this directory were the (only?) way to track the versions of some of the dependencies in my Android project.

e.g. one of my recent commits included this change:

[image]

The problem is that the xml files in this folder undergo a lot of meaningless changes (mostly changes in the order of lines) which are annoying to manually ignore when committing.

e.g.:

[image]

**Is there a solution that would allow me to keep track of the dependencies version updates, while preventing this kind of meaningless diffs?**

Comment: Dependency versions are in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare In the case of the android support library of my example, I did not add this dependency myself in any of my `build.gradle` files. I suspect it may be a dependency of some direct dependency I actually use.

Comment: One other reason I'd rather not rely on `build.gradle` is because I use dynamic versioning for some dependencies (e.g. `com.foo:4.+`). I know it is supposed to be a bad practice, but I like how it provides a convenient way to get upgrades seamslessly while still being notified of such upgrades (via the filename changes in `.idea/libraries/`).

Comment: well, whether you like it or not, build.gradle is where your dependencies are being managed and are picked up by android studio.

Comment: @RaGe Sure. But tracking `build.gradle` in source control is NOT enough to track changes in dependencies versions.